# Is it possible to loop through a switch statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a standard slider which has two buttons to go through the images. However I want to make it modular. So that the end user can add 200 images if they like. I use Jquery to hide and show the images. But I don't want to write 200 if statement, so I used a switch and wanted to loop through that switch which changes the cases active slide to display and hide the other element and stops if the amount of items has been reached.

But I have been having some issues, is there someone more experienced than me that can help

```
$('.slider-wrap').each( function() {
            let itemsAmount =  $('.slider-img', $(this)).length;
            console.log(itemsAmount);
        });


        let currentPic = 0;

        $('.sliderbuttonPlus').on('click', () => {
            currentPic++;

            let itemsAmount =  $('.slider-img', $('.slider-wrap')).length;
                        
            switch(currentPic) {

                case 0:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-0').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 1:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-1').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 2:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-2').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 3:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-3').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 4:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-4').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 5:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-5').css('display', 'block');
                break; 

                case 6:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-6').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 7:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-7').css('display', 'block');
                break;

                case 8:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-8').css('display', 'block');
                break;
                
                case 9:
                    $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#slider-block-image-9').css('display', 'block');
                break;

            }   
                if(currentPic > itemsAmount) {
                        currentPic = itemsAmount;
                };

                console.log(currentPic);
        });
    

        $('.sliderbuttonMinus').on('click', () => {
            currentPic--;

        switch(currentPic) {
            case 0:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-0').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 1:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-1').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 2:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-2').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 3:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-3').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 4:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-4').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 5:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-5').css('display', 'block');
            break;   
            case 6:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-6').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 7:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-7').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 8:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-8').css('display', 'block');
            break;
            case 9:
                $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
                $('#slider-block-image-9').css('display', 'block');
            break;

        } 
        
        if (currentPic <= 0){
            currentPic = 0;
        };   
            console.log(currentPic);
        });

        if (currentPic === 0) {

            $('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
            $('#slider-block-image-0').css('display', 'block');
            
        } 

        console.log(currentPic);     

    });
```

HTML displayed on the site

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="button-wrap">
        <button class="sliderbuttonMinus">Links</button>
    </div>


        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/warhammer-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-0" style="display: block;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/xcom-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-1" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Skyrim-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-2" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Skylines-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-3" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Sea-of-thieves-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-4" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Mario-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-5" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Minecraft-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-6" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Overwatch-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-7" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Half-life-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-8" style="display: none;">


        
        <img class="slider-img" src="https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/hearthstone-1.jpg" alt="" id="slider-block-image-9" style="display: none;">


         <div class="button-wrap">      
        <button class="sliderbuttonPlus">Rechts</button>
    </div>     
</div>
```

PHP

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="button-wrap">
        <button class="sliderbuttonMinus">Links</button>
    </div>

<?php
// Check rows exists.
if( have_rows('afbeeldingen_slider') ):

    $x = 0;
    // Loop through rows.
    while( have_rows('afbeeldingen_slider') ) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $image = get_sub_field('slider_image');
        $image_url = $image['url'];
        $image_alt = $image['alt'];
        ?>

        <img class="slider-img" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" id="slider-block-image-<?php echo $x?>">


        <?php
        // Do something...
        $x++;
    // End loop.
    endwhile;

// No value.
else :
    // Do something...
endif;


?> <div class="button-wrap">      
        <button class="sliderbuttonPlus">Rechts</button>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use an array of images and then the index related to the numeric portion of the `img` ID ~ such as `id="slider-block-image-0"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only one part, with a dynamic index or indicator of the picture.

```
$('.slider-img').css('display', 'none');
$('#slider-block-image-' + currentPic).css('display', 'block');
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Wow, who would have known that the solution would be this simple, I have been breaking my brain of this for a while now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You could also create an HTML Collection with $('.slider-img') and access the image you want to switch to via $('.slider-img').eq(currentPic);

You could use other logic than a switch statement and the code would be more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the hardcoded `img` elements within the HTML and the repetitive declarations within the javascript/jQuery code you could, as I suggested, use an array to power the entire slideshow. With an array you need simply add additional `img` sources and it should then run with no additional coding. This was hastily written in vanilla js

```js
// the index that points to current active picture
let cpic=0;

const d=document;
const parent = d.querySelector('div.slider-wrap');
const child = parent.firstElementChild;
const _CN='active';

const insertafter = (node, ref) => {
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(node, ref.nextSibling)
};

// modify the global index variable `cpic`
// depending upon which button was clicked.
const clickhandler=function(e){
  switch( this.dataset.dir ){
    case 'minus':cpic--;break;
    case 'plus':cpic++;break;
  }
  if( cpic < 0 )cpic=images.length - 1;
  if( cpic > images.length - 1 )cpic=0;
  /*
    remove active class from all images
    and add to currently selected
  */
  parent.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img,i)=>{
    img.classList.remove(_CN);
    if( i==cpic )img.classList.add(_CN);
  })
};



const path = 'https://zelfbouwcontainer.online/wp-content/';
/*
  This array powers the slide show. Add as many items
  to it as needed.
*/
const images = [
  '/uploads/2021/11/warhammer-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/xcom-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Skyrim-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Skylines-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Sea-of-thieves-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Mario-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Minecraft-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Overwatch-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/Half-life-1.jpg',
  '/uploads/2021/11/hearthstone-1.jpg'
];

/* dynamically add all images to the page, hidden based upn css class */
images.forEach((src, i) => {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = path + src;
  img.className = 'slider-img';
  img.id = 'slider-block-image-' + i;
  img.dataset.id = i;

  insertafter(img, child)
});

/* set the first image visible */
parent.querySelector('img:first-of-type').classList.add(_CN);



d.querySelectorAll('button[data-dir]').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',clickhandler));
```

```css
.slider-wrap img{
  display:none;
}
.slider-wrap img.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <button data-dir='minus' class="sliderbuttonMinus">Links</button>
  </div>
  <!-- dynamically add images here from array -->
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <button data-dir='plus' class="sliderbuttonPlus">Rechts</button>
  </div>
</div>
```